# Cant place an image at the bottom of a pdf file using fpdf python

Tags: python, pdf, pyfpdf

I am using Python and I'm trying to place three images that cover the entire page.
The last image creats and jumps to the next page, I think beacuse of the 'footer'.
How can I disable this footer or overcome it?

```
from PIL import Image
from fpdf import FPDF


class PDF(FPDF):
    pass


def imagex(self):
    self.set_xy(0, 0)
    self.image(fr'C:\Users\user\Desktop\pictures\1.jpeg', link='', type='', w=210, h=100)
    self.set_xy(0, 100)
    self.image(fr'C:\Users\user\Desktop\pictures\2.jpeg', link='', type='', w=210, h=100)
#This is where the picture jumps
    self.set_xy(0, 200) 
    self.image(fr'C:\Users\user\Desktop\pictures\3.jpeg', link='', type='', w=210, h=100)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pdf = PDF()
    pdf.add_page()
    imagex(pdf)
    pdf.output(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.pdf', 'F')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this below solution:

```
def imagex(self, w, h):
    w_Image=w
    h_Image=h
    self.image(fr'C:\Users\user\Desktop\pictures\1.jpeg', 0, 0, w=w_Image, h=h_Image)
    self.image(fr'C:\Users\user\Desktop\pictures\2.jpeg', 0, h_Image, w=w_Image, h=h_Image)
    self.image(fr'C:\Users\user\Desktop\pictures\3.jpeg', 0, h_Image*2, w=w_Image, h=h_Image)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pdf = PDF()
    pdf.add_page()
    imagex(pdf,210,100)
    pdf.output(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.pdf', 'F')
```

I tried to rewrite your code and assessed based on my data. In fact, you must set the location of each picture sequentially. Instead of using `self.set_xy` I embedded `(x,y)` location in `self.image("file_path", x,y, w,h)`